# mongodb after restoring replica-set from backup the primary is not master

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

after recovering replica-set from a snapshot (for testing)
when I run commands on the primary I got error

```
not master and slaveOk=false
```

does primary not equal to master? 
I got this output for the command `rs.isMaster()` on the primary.

```
shard2-replset:PRIMARY> rs.isMaster()
{
    "hosts" : [
        "mongo-stage-rs-01-a.prod:27018",
        "mongo-stage-rs-01-b.prod:27018"
    ],
    "setName" : "shard2-replset",
    "setVersion" : 17,
    "ismaster" : false,
    "secondary" : true,
    "primary" : "mongo-stage-rs-01-b.prod:27018",
    "me" : "mongo-stage-rs-01-b.prod:27018",
    "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000028"),
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2019-05-15T17:09:13.275Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 4,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

is it make sence that the "primary" and "me" is the same, but yet `"secondary" : true` and `"ismaster" : false,`

```
    "ismaster" : false,
    "secondary" : true,
    "primary" : "mongo-stage-rs-01-b.prod:27018",
    "me" : "mongo-stage-rs-01-b.prod:27018",
```

mongodb version 3.2

Comment: It says "mongo-stage-rs-01-b.prod:27018" as both `primary` and `secondary`. It is not possible. what is the `rs.status()` value.

Comment: already fixed so I cannot add the output now, 
the solution was from https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/restore-sharded-cluster/ 
to start the shard with `mongod --setParameter=recoverShardingState=false --replSet <replSetName>`
then run: 
`use admin
db.system.version.remove(
   { _id: "minOpTimeRecovery" },
   { writeConcern: { w: "majority" } }
)`